# Can threads have more than one argument?

Tags: c, arguments, pthreads

Can threads have more than one argument without using a struct?

So... kind of like:

```
pthread_create(&file_thread, NULL, merge_thread, sortedFiles, number);
```

... where 'number' is the extra argument?

Thanks,
Hristo

Comment: See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You'll have to define a struct to contain the various parameters, and pass a pointer to an instance of the struct as the single `void*` argument to `pthread_create`.

Comment: I was hoping there would be another way. Thanks.

Comment: Hristo: The judicious use of a wrapper function can hide the use of the structure for you.